# A runtime generated image ( .gif ) doesn't show in an Image element in a WPF UI

Tags: wpf

I have made a parser using ANTLR4 that builds a syntax tree and generates its visual represantation in a .gif file at runtime (using Graphviz). I would like to display this .gif file in an image element in the UI in response to the a ParseGrammar button click. So i use the following code in the handler which works as i expect unless i remove the image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; line. What happens in this case is that the syntax tree is not displayed in the Image element without any exception produced.

```
string gifFilename = Facade.MTestBenchDirectory + "SyntaxTree" + ".gif";
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
Facade.ParseGrammar(m_grammarFilename);
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource =new Uri(gifFilename,UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
imageSyntaxTree.Source = image;
```

If i remove the line the .gif file is not displayed in the Image element.Below you can see the XAML code i have used where the Image element is towards the last lines of the code.

```
<Window x:Class="UOPBisonUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UOPBisonUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" Click="OpenMenuItem_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" Click="SaveMenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Run">
            <MenuItem Header="_Parse Grammar" Click="ParseGrammarMenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_About"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Name="grammarEditorTextBox"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0"
                                CenterY="0"
                                ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, Path=Value}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider, Path=Value}"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Image  Name="imageSyntaxTree"></Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Slider Grid.Row="1"
                    Name="zoomSlider"
                    Value="2"
                    Minimum="0.1"
                    Maximum="4"/>
        </Grid>            
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I have searched a lot and there is no explicit explanation for such a simple issue. That is, why the  image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; line is necessary for the syntaxtree to load and displayed at runtime in the Image element. Can you explain the reason or provide some source to read about this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As a note, are you sure that `Facade.MTestBenchDirectory + "SyntaxTree" + ".gif"` always is a relative path? Why don't you use `Path.Combine()` and `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`? Besides that, setting `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` should only be necessary if the BitmapImage is supposed to be loaded immediately during the EndInit call, e.g. if you want to delete the file afterwards.

Comment: I am sure it is a relative path. Nevertheless, i have change as you suggest and it didn't work without the OnLoad switch.

Comment: Are you doing anything with the file after you created the BitmapImage?

Comment: Before the ParserGrammar method completes the Graphviz tool is called to produce the .gif. and this fullfills the method. Afterwards and synchronously the the code creating the Bitmap source is executed.